# encoding error creating and writing .h file

Tags: python

With python 3 I use the open() and write() functions to create and write a .h file.

If the file extension is .txt the file displays special characters like
'ñ' and 'á' correctly, but changing the extension to .h the characters doen't display correctly.

I create the file and then write something on it

```py
string = 'ñ'
f= open("headerfile.h","w+",encoding='utf-8')
f.write(string)
f.close()
```

Comment: Is it the same editor to read the both files?

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely due to the program you're using to *view* the .h file vs. the .txt file. The content of the files isn't going to be any different. Probably the editor you're using with the .h file doesn't handle utf-8.

To confirm, if you're on Linux or Mac, do this:

```
od -cx headerfile.txt
od -cx headerfile.h
```

which will show you the raw hex octets in each file.
You can also just do `cmp headerfile.txt headerfile.h` to see whether they're identical.
If they're not identical, come back here and show the output of the above commands.

Comment: While I agree with you, I think this should be a commend :)